# My time converter is not adding the minutes

Tags: python

I am going to use this converter as part of a project in mind but it doesn't seem to work as expected. The hours are correct, but it doesn't add the minutes. I can't seem to understand what's wrong here but I think it's in the "splitting" part. The converted vale of "9:30" is 540 in the output which is lacking 30 minutes. The same goes for "14:30". Thank you for answering this.

This is my code:

```
schedule1 = [
    ["8:00", "9:30"],
    ["10:00", "11:00"],
    ["13:00", "14:30"],
    ["16:00", "17:00"]
]

def convert_schedule(schedule):
    converted_schedule = []
    for item in schedule:
        start = item[0]
        end = item[1]
        start_hour, start_minute = start.split(':')
        end_hour, end_minute = end.split(':')
        start_time = int(start_hour) * 60 + int(start_minute)
        end_time = int(end_hour) * 60 + int(start_minute)
        print(f'{start_time}-{end_time}')
```

Comment: You've got `start_minute` in the expression for `end_time`

Comment: If it is not a requirement that you implement this yourself, you should probably use an existing library like `datetime`.

Comment: Although the question could be categorised as "caused by typo", which would be sufficient grounds to close it, it would be worth keeping it open in case somebody wants to add an answer showing how it can be done using `datetime`.

Comment: Keep it even simpler, just unpack them in the loop expression, i.e., `for start, end in schedule:`

Comment: @Kent_Erbert It's likely to be closed here, but you could ask about the corrected piece of code over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get more feedback (and probably even a `datetime` version). And really, you're doing fine for two weeks of coding!

Comment: @alaniwi The "converted_schedule" is actually there because it's used in the lines of code following the one that I posted. This is just a small part of that. I just sent this part because I thought the other part was insignificant to this question.

Comment: I agree with what has been said by others here: for SO this question is of the category "caused by a typo / not reproducible", but once you have it working, you could go to Code Review to ask for feedback to improve your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already been mentioned in the comments you could use the datetime library for that. This is one way of doing it, but there are for sure other (maybe more efficient) ways:

**What is happening in here?** First of all I converted the end time to a datetime object and the start time to a timedelta object to substract them from each other. In the end I converted the result back to a string object.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

schedule1 = [
    ["8:00", "9:30"],
    ["10:00", "11:00"],
    ["13:00", "14:30"],
    ["16:00", "17:00"]
]

for period in schedule1:
    print((datetime.strptime(period[1], '%H:%M') - timedelta(hours=datetime.strptime(period[0], '%H:%M').hour, minutes=datetime.strptime(period[0], '%H:%M').minute)).strftime('%H:%M'))
```

**Why datetime?** Use everything that makes life easier for you. Existing libraries like the built in standard ones will help you to achieve your goal with less lines of code which in turn makes your project cleaner. Another point is you dont have to care about every edge case that is maybe possible because modules and libraries can take care fore you. That does not mean you dont have to test your code, but it makes life easier.